# Jquery - Image not changing onselect of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu with different car models, when user selects a model from the dropdown the car image needs to change, but it is not changing. Here is my code:

```
 <h2 class="model">A6
<img src="images/3.jpg" id="image" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>

<select id="image" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="2">A6</option>
    <option value="3">A8</option>
</select>

var pictureList = [
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg",
     ];

$('#image').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#image').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

[image]

Comment: where is your dropdown ?

Comment: your select menu has the same id as your img?

Comment: you need to apply change event on dropdown not on image

Comment: @AshokDamani I just added it...sorry

Comment: @Marilee..i guess it would be far better easy to write script on unique id's rather than having same for multiple controls in the same page

Answer (score 2):

2 problems:

1. You use the same id for the `<img />` and the `<select />`
2. An array starts with index 0 not with 1. So your HTML for the `<select />` should look like this:

   `<select id="image" class="modelSelect">
       <option value="0" selected>A4</option>
       <option value="1">A6</option>
       <option value="2">A8</option>
   </select>`

Comment: I am going to write same things you mention. After posting, i saw your told these things already. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your id is the same

do like this:

```
<select id="imageSelect" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="2">A6</option>
    <option value="3">A8</option>
</select>

$('#imageSelect').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#imageSelect').val());
    $('img').attr("src", pictureList[val]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this as you have same id for both, you need more descriptive selector or change the **ids** so that both should not be same:

```
$('select#image').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('select#image').val());
    $('img#image').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The id image `$('#image')` is the balise img and not the dropdown so modify one id to match the good one and don't forget that an array begin to 0 and not 1 ;)

```
 <h2 class="model">A6
<img src="images/3.jpg" id="image" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>

<select id="selectimage" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="0" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="1">A6</option>
    <option value="2">A8</option>
</select>

var pictureList = [
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg",
     ];

$('#image').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#selectimage').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
// added your image id within its parent
$('img #image').attr("src", pictureList[val]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 class="model">A6
<img src="images/3.jpg" id="image" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>

<select id="ddlImage" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="2">A6</option>
    <option value="3">A8</option>
</select>

var pictureList = [
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg",
     ];

$(#ddlImage).change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#ddlImage).val());
    $(#img).attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/97uue/1/

HTML:  ( Change Image ID, Select option value, because array index start from 0. )

```
<h2 class="model">A6
<img src="images/3.jpg" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>

<select id="image" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="0" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="1">A6</option>
    <option value="2">A8</option>
</select>
```

JS Code:

```
var pictureList = [
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg",
     ];

$('#image').change(function () {
    var ImgName = $('#image').val();    
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[ImgName]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are listening to the change event on the image. Both the image and the dropdown have the same id, they need to be unique.

Use a different id for the dropdown and it will attach the event handler to the correct element.

```
$('#image-dropdown').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#image-dropdown').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val - 1]);
});
```

Note that I also changed the index for the picture list to start from 0 rather than 1.

And change the id for the select tag in the html:

```
<select id="image-dropdown" class="modelSelect">
    <option value="1" selected>A4</option>
    <option value="2">A6</option>
    <option value="3">A8</option>
</select>
```